# Redirect a Domain to different .php files

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, dns, subdomain

I have a webhoster which does not serve Name aliases for my DNS Domain. I have 2 different domains. Both should be redirected to different targets (e.g. /index.php , /abc/index2.php), but at the same root-server.

How could i use both domains with one server with PHP or a tool (ubuntu)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the host header `HTTP_HOST` of the request to know on which domain the request is.

```
if (strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"], "domaina.com") !== false) {
  header('Location: '.$urldomaina);
}
else if (strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"], "domainb.com") !== false)
{
    header('Location: '.$urldomainb);
}
```

Comment: You may get an error if you access it from localhost.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your first Domain (domain.com) on your webspace, map the other Domain (domain.org) to the same Webspace (this is named Domain-Alias).

Now you can redirect each Domain in the direction you need with .htaccess (mod_rewrite):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://redirect.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.org$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://redirect.org/$1 [L,R=301]
```